# How to map multiple attributes from source to a multivalued attribute on target in xsl transformations

Tags: xml, web-services, xslt, wsdl

I have to use xsl transformations for mapping from one wsdl to another.In my source wsdl I have an attribute which has multiple values for example the result from the sorce wsdl is

```
<Groups>
<group>Group1</group>
<group>Group2</group>
</Groups>
```

The type of the attribute to which this is to be mapped in the target wsdl is :

```
    <xs:complexType name="attributesMultiValued">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="values" type="xs:string"
                  nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

I tried with simple for-each, but this is not getting the values.

Sample transformation code :

```
<attributesMultiValued>
  <name>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="no">Groups</xsl:text>
  </name>
  <xsl:for-each select="tns:Groups">
    <values>
      <xsl:value-of select="group"/>
    </values>
  </xsl:for-each>
</attributesMultiValued>
```

How is it possible to get all the `group` in  `values`?

Comment: **1.** You are confusing *attributes* and *elements*. **2.** Please post your XSLT, along with your expected output.

Comment: I have added the xsl transformation in the question.

Comment: You appear to be trying to output an xsi:nil attribute with a value such as "Group1". Why? The value of xsi:nil must be a boolean.

Comment: Yeah.That was a mistake.I have corrected that.But still I am not able to get the values of the groups.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is what you're trying to do:

```
<attributesMultiValued>
  <name>Groups</name>
  <xsl:for-each select="tns:Groups/tns:Group">
    <values>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </values>
  </xsl:for-each>
</attributesMultiValued>
```

A better approach is to use templates:

```
<attributesMultiValued>
  <name>Groups</name>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="tns:Groups/tns:Group" />
</attributesMultiValued>

<!-- A bit further down... -->
<xsl:template match="tns:Group">
  <values>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
  </values>
</xsl:template>
```

However, I can't be sure that either of these is what you need without a more extensive example of your XML (for example, where is the `tns:` namespace coming from? It's not shown in your example XML.

Comment: I tried the first method.I am not getting any values, not even the values column appears in the result after transformation.

Comment: @cmmuser In that case please present a more thorough example of your actual XML and XSLT.

Comment: I have added the complete schema of the attribute to which I am mapping.

Comment: @cmmuser That was the one thing I didn't ask for. If the solution I provided is not producing any values, then it's because I lack information about your XML or about your XSLT. Please provide a more extensive example of both.