# xsl transformation to the same unbounded attribute

Tags: xml, web-services, xslt, wsdl

I have to do a transformation from a source wsdl to a target wsdl.
In my source wsdl I have 4 attributes.The following gives the result returned from the source wsdl:

```
<Role>
<roleName>Role1</roleName>
<StartDate>2014-08-26</StartDate>
<primary>true</primary>
</Role>
```

This is to be mapped to attribute which can have more than one occurrence(unbounded).

The attribute is of the form :

```
<xs:complexType name="Attr">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="attributeName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="Attributes" type="tns:dataValue"
                  nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="dataValue">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

Here I want to map name of the attribute to the name in dataValue and the value of the attribute to value of DataValue.
For example if roleName is role1, then name is roleName and value is role1.Similarly I want to map for the other 2 attributes also.

I am expecting an output of the following format :

```
<Attr>
<attributeName>Role</attributeName>
<Attributes>
<name>RoleName</name>
<value>Role1</value>
</Attributes>
<Attributes>
<name>StartDate</name>
<value>2014-08-26</value>
</Attributes>
<Attributes>
<name>primary</name>
<value>true</value>
</Attributes>
</Attr>
```

Comment: Can you show an actual example of the XML you expect to be output in this case? And if you have tried some XSLT already, posting that would help too. Thank you very much.

Comment: How is this different from your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759154/how-to-map-multiple-attributes-from-source-to-a-multivalued-attribute-on-target

Comment: Also, please read [**How do I ask a good question?**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and review how you're asking questions and [**accepting**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/234215) answers.   *6 accepts out of 56 questions looks amiss.*

Comment: @TimC: I have added the expected output format.I wanted to know if its possible to do such a mapping with the unbounded element Attributes in Attr.

Comment: @michael.hor257k : This is different from the question you pointed out. In the other question,the mapping is to be done from a single element on the source to a single element on the target. In this case mapping is to be done from multiple element on the source to same element(which is defined to have unbounded ocuurrences) on the target.

Comment: @kjhughes : I have quite few number questions for which people have just commented and not answered.Also there are some questions for which I didn't get a satisfactory answer. Thanks for the suggestions.Will revisit my questions and accept the Answers if any answer is to be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that is really your XML, then you would simply have a template that matched the `Role` element....

```
 <xsl:template match="Role">
```

You would then use the `local-name()` function to output the name....

```
<attributeName>
    <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
</attributeName>
```

And to get the "attributes" (which in the original XML are elements, not attributes), you can iterate over them with `xsl:for-each` for example:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="*">
```

And you would use the `local-name()` function again to get the element name. Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="Role">
      <Attr>
         <attributeName>
            <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
         </attributeName>
         <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <Attributes>
               <name>
                  <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
               </name>
               <value>
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
               </value>
            </Attributes>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </Attr>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is applied to the following XML shown in your question....

```
<Role>
    <roleName>Role1</roleName>
    <StartDate>2014-08-26</StartDate>
    <primary>true</primary>
</Role>
```

Then the following is output

```
<Attr>
   <attributeName>Role</attributeName>
   <Attributes>
      <name>roleName</name>
      <value>Role1</value>
   </Attributes>
   <Attributes>
      <name>StartDate</name>
      <value>2014-08-26</value>
   </Attributes>
   <Attributes>
      <name>primary</name>
      <value>true</value>
   </Attributes>
</Attr>
```

Comment: using name() and node() with the above code instead of local-name and . helped me get the required transformation